# Validate datagrid cell comparing with the sum of another cell and a function

Tags: sql, vb.net, function, validation, datagrid

I have a datagrid for which I want to check, when I input the value in cell of the DataGridView1.Columns(6), if the cell value of DataGridView1.Columns(7) is bigger than cell value for DataGridView1.Columns(6) plus the result of a function which has the argument as DataGridView1.Columns(1) and gets the total of previous inserted values from DataGridView1.Columns(6).

What I don't know:

- where to make this check and how to do it?
- how to assign the argument of the function in the checking formula for each row of the datagrid?

The function is:

```
Public Shared Function getproddeclarata(ByVal nrfpo As String) As Integer
    Dim total As Integer
    Dim con As New SqlConnection
    Try
        con = New SqlConnection("Data Source=SVNAV;Initial Catalog=NAV_Vermorel_Live;User ID=sa;Password=1234")
        Using cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT cast(SUM([Productie Declarata]) as Decimal(18,2)) as TotalOreDeclarate FROM [SC Vermorel SRL$ProductieZilnica] WHERE FPO = @nrfpo", con)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nrfpo", nrfpo)
            con.Open()
            total = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
            con.Close()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    Finally
        If con IsNot Nothing Then
            If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then                    '
                con.Close()
            End If
            con.Dispose()
        End If
    End Try
    Return total
End Function
```

Comment: So you are populating the datagridviewfrom SQL? Are you trying to check the data when the data is being assigned to your datagridview?

Comment: hello! yes. the datagrid is populated by calling a function. i am trying to check data when i input values in specific cells of this function called datagrid.                                                                                          Private Sub frmFpoList_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim dt As DataTable = functiicomune.getFpo(functiicomune.ProceseazaSCH(Now), Now.Date)      DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you can handel the event `DataGridView1_CellEndEdit` like :

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellEndEdit(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellEndEdit
        Try
            Dim rw As DataGridView = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)

          If e.ColumnIndex = 6 Then
            If IsNumeric (rw(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value) andalso rw(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value)>0  Then
                If rw(7, e.RowIndex).Value > rw(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value + getproddeclarata(rw(1, e.RowIndex).Value.ToString()) Then

                    'Same code here

                End If
            End If
        End If

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: hello! tks. it doesnt work. its strange also: if i put any value in the cell less than 7 it triggers the formula. for anything else bigger than 7 it doesnt. for example: the quantity in the cell for column index 7 is 11 and i tried to input 15 in the cell coresponding to column index 6 and it allowed me to do that.

Comment: ohhh it works! wait! im idiot! but how do i reset the value of the cell back to 0? i mean the users put a qty, the message appears, but the qty remains in the cell. i need to stop the user from validating that wrong qty.

Comment: you can do a test for evcalating the value :look at my answer i edit it

Comment: tks alot. you gave me good directions. i hope i can solve the problem with the cell that has to stay in edit mode until value meets criteria.